# How to load CSS background Image in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I've a background image in CSS / SCSS file . Written as `background-image:url(..);` and the image is in the rails assets folder.

I'm trying `image_url()` but it is not working . And how can I do that .. I have even tried to put that image in public folder. But it didn't work either .

**Code:**

```
background-image:image-url('header.png');
```

Directory of assets is :
    1. stylesheets
    2. fonts
    3. images
    4. javascripts

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you  'view page source' of the generated css file?

Comment: Yes I did.. and as it suppose to show ... it is having the image path and image . I used  image_url()  and still its not loading in the front view . Maybe I am doing something wrong . Can you help with more information?

Comment: If the CSS generated is showing the correct URL, then it doesn't sound like image_url() issue. Is the image accessible from browser (when not in background-image property)?